# Wolfram Script Console Doesn't Close Automatically on Windows

Tags: windows, installation, scripting

I'm not exactly sure how Wolfram Scripts are supposed to work.  So I wrote a simple one to configure MaTeX for me so that all I have to do is double click it on a system where I've installed Mathematica 11.3 in order to get MaTeX installed and working.  However, when I run the code by double clicking the .wls script file on Windows 10, a black box pops up and never disappears; it looks like this:

[image]

Notice how, even though all the code finished executing, the console window stayed open.  This is undesirable.  **Is there anything that I can put at the end of my Mathematica .wls script file to tell the console window to close immediately after running?**  I tried putting the line "exit" at the very end of the script, but this still didn't work either.

Comment: `Quit` instead of `exit` perhaps?

Comment: @user6014, alas, none of "Quit", "quit", "Exit", or "exit" make the console window close after running.

Comment: Try running 'exit' as an external command?  http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/ExternalPrograms.html

Comment: Unfortunately, that command has not worked for me either.